# Cannot configure local cluster dask worker directory

Tags: dask

I'm trying to configure the [dask worker space](http://distributed.readthedocs.io/en/latest/worker.html) in the `config.yaml` file (version Dask 0.16.0 )  .
I tried adding

```
local_dir: /path/to/ssd
```

or

```
local-directory: /path/to/ssd
```

or

```
local_directory: /path/to/ssd
```

but i'm still finding the `dask-worker-space` in the same directory where the py file is running from.

I"m I missing something from [dask_worker.py](https://github.com/dask/distributed/blob/73ecaea7e18c7bd351a3db62c1491f16a1dc6037/distributed/cli/dask_worker.py) ?

Answer (score 5):

You can set the local_directory when starting dask workers

```
cluster = LocalCluster(..., local_dir="/path/to/mydir")
```

or

```
dask-worker ... --local-directory /path/to/mydir
```

Comment: for `cluster = LocalCluster(..., local_directory="/path/to/mydir")` I'm getting `TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument local_directory`

Comment: The `distributed.__version__` is 1.20.2

Comment: I believe it is `LocalCluster(..., local_dir="/path/to/dir")`

Comment: Why is this option not documented?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like [the option does not exist](https://github.com/dask/distributed/blob/master/distributed/config.py) in the configuration file.

Answer (score 0):

I use distributed version 2021.02.0 and i can set the worker directory this way

```
cluster = LocalCluster(name="New Cluster", local_directory="/tmp")
```